# How do I determine if a file contains a specific class in SrcML.Net

Tags: c#

I want to display if the Android "ServiceTestCase" Class is being used in any of the Directories.

The Program currently

1) Displays the Sensor Types the File uses

2) Displays the number of Implementations of the "onSensorChanged" Method

3) Displays the other functions that call the "onSensorChange" Implementation.

How do I display Classes?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ABB.SrcML;
using ABB.SrcML.Data;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections;

namespace CodeAnalysisToolkit
{
[TestFixture]
public class SimpleAnalyticsCalculator_Thesis
{
    //------Test Case Class------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [TestCase]
    public void CalculateSimpleProjectStats()
    {
        int NumOfApps = 5;


        //-----------Current Working Method to Get sub directories -------------------------

        // Get list of files in the specific directory.
        string[] TopDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\School\Grad School (Comp Sci)\Thesis\Apps\",
            "*.*",
            SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        // Display all the files.
        //for (int i = 0; i <= NumOfApps; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(TopDirectories[i]);
        //}

        //Print out all Top Sub Directoies for Specified Path 
        //foreach (string file in TopDirectories)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(file);
        //}

        //----------End of Print Sub directory Method----------------------------------------


        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfApps; i++)
        {
            var dataProject = new DataProject<CompleteWorkingSet>(TopDirectories[i],
                Path.GetFullPath(TopDirectories[i]),
                "..//..//..//SrcML");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Debug.WriteLine("#############################################");
            Debug.WriteLine("Parsing " + TopDirectories[i]);

            dataProject.UpdateAsync().Wait();

            NamespaceDefinition globalNamespace;
            Assert.That(dataProject.WorkingSet.TryObtainReadLock(5000, out globalNamespace));

            DisplaySensorTypes(globalNamespace);
            //DisplayWhetherAppIsUnitTested();           
            DisplayCallsToOnSensorChanged(globalNamespace);
        }
    }


    //-------Display Sensor Type Class--------------------------------------------------------------

    private void DisplaySensorTypes(NamespaceDefinition globalNamespace)
    {
        var getDefaultSensorCalls = from statement in globalNamespace.GetDescendantsAndSelf()
                                    from expression in statement.GetExpressions()
                                    from call in expression.GetDescendantsAndSelf<MethodCall>()                                     
                                    where call.Name == "getDefaultSensor"
                                    select call;

        foreach (var call in getDefaultSensorCalls)
        {
            if (call.Arguments.Any())
            {
                var firstArg = call.Arguments.First();
                var components = firstArg.Components;
                if (components.Count() == 3 &&
                    components.ElementAt(0).ToString() == "Sensor" &&
                    components.ElementAt(1).ToString() == ".")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("sensor " + components.ElementAt(2).ToString() + " found");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void DisplayWhetherAppIsUnitTested()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }




    //-------Display Calls to OnSensorChanged Class------------------------------------------------

    private void DisplayCallsToOnSensorChanged(NamespaceDefinition globalNamespace)
    {
        var senChangedMethods = from method in globalNamespace.GetDescendants<MethodDefinition>()
            where method.Name == "onSensorChanged"
            select method;

        if (senChangedMethods.Count() == 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This File Does not contain any Sensor Change Mehtods");
        }

        else
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("----- ");
            Debug.WriteLine("\r\n");
            Debug.WriteLine(senChangedMethods.Count() + " Implementations of " + senChangedMethods.First().GetFullName());
            Debug.WriteLine("----- ");

            int n = senChangedMethods.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                var senChangedMethod = senChangedMethods.ElementAt(i);
                Debug.WriteLine("Implementations of onSensorChaged # " + (i + 1) + ": " + senChangedMethod.GetFullName());

                //"GetCallsToSelf" returns the number of times the number is called
                var callsToSenChanged = senChangedMethod.GetCallsToSelf();
                for (int j = 0; j < callsToSenChanged.Count(); j++)
                {
                    var callerMethod = callsToSenChanged.ElementAt(j).ParentStatement.GetAncestorsAndSelf<MethodDefinition>();
                    if (callerMethod.Any())
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("   Called by --> " + callerMethod.ElementAt(0).GetFullName());
                    }
                }
                //Debug.WriteLine("----- ");
            }
        }  //End of Else does not Equal 0 Check
    }



    //-------Display Test Class--------------------------------------------------------------



}
```

}